# Mysql query running COUNT every time the same value is fetched

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am currently using Laravels QueryBuilder to fetch all users and the number of open tickets they have.

The query looks like this:

```
return DB::table('users')
                 ->leftjoin('tickets', 'users.organisation', '=', 'tickets.organisation')
                 ->leftjoin('tickets_statuses', 'tickets.ticket_id', '=', 'tickets_statuses.ticket_id')
                 ->select(
                     'users.organisation',
                     DB::raw('COUNT(tickets.ticket_id) as tickets')
                 )
                 ->where('tickets_statuses.status_id', 0)
                 ->where('users.admin', false)
                 ->groupby('users.organisation')
                 ->get();
```

The issue is, I may have 6 users that belong to the same organisation. So if 80 open tickets belong to the organisation, the query would do 80 x 6 for some reason resulting in 480 open ticket count when it should be 80.

/** EDIT **/

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for users
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `organisation` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent_account` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=50 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


+----+---------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| id | name                      | email                               | organisation                    |
+----+---------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|  6 | Bruce Mayert MD           | Hodkiewicz.Nicolette@gmail.com      | Corkery Group                   |
| 30 | Mr. Willard Bogisich III  | Rowena13@gmail.com                  | Corkery Group                   |
| 31 | Jacinthe Murphy           | Schuyler57@Pfeffer.org              | Corkery Group                   |
| 32 | Zelda Koss PhD            | iTillman@Spinka.biz                 | Corkery Group                   |
| 33 | Mr. Kevon McCullough MD   | kMarks@Green.org                    | Corkery Group                   |
| 34 | Prof. Cleveland Prohaska  | Ibrahim.Schneider@hotmail.com       | Corkery Group                   |
```

As you can see, multiple users belong to an organisation. Now if I ran the following query:

```
SELECt ticket_id from tickets where organisation = 'Corkery Group';
```

I receive the following:

`80 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

From the query, I am wanting to get the organisation name and count all the tickets that belong to an organisation.

When I run the original query, it returns a result set of 480 rows when it should only return 80 rows.

Comment: you should use cache

Comment: what do you mean when `COUNT(tickets.organisation) as tickets` and `->groupby('users.organisation', 'tickets.organisation')` later on? My guess is: you should remove `tickets.organisation` from **groupby**. so it could be just:  `->groupby('users.organisation')`

Comment: @Alex thanks for your answer. I've updated it to `COUNT(tickets.ticket_id) as tickets` - that statement just counts open tickets per user. Unfortunately, having just `groupby('users.organisation')` still returns the same result.

Comment: post your database schema, raw sample of data and expected result please

Comment: @Alex i've updated my question.

Comment: you did an update but it is not complete at all. your `users` table has 10 columns, but in data sample you have just 4. in your query there are `tickets` and `tickets_statuses` tables involved, but you didn't post table definitions and sample of data. and you didn't provide expected result. By the way if your `SELECt ticket_id from tickets where organisation = 'Corkery Group';` return 80 rows it doesn't mean that you have only 80 records there in the table. Your query in the post has no any filter by compnany, so maybe 480 records are correct

Answer (score 0):

There was a very good answer here [Why do the results of this MySQL query get multiplied by each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707833/why-do-the-results-of-this-mysql-query-get-multiplied-by-each-other) that put me in the right direction.

In my scenario, for every user with an organisation the `COUNT()` would be executed. The issue is, if I have 6 users which are part of one organisation, it's going to run the `COUNT()` statement six times.

So going back to my query, I didn't need the users table. It was irrelevant because I was only trying to access organisations with tickets & the organisation name - all of which are stored in the `tickets` & `tickets_statuses` tables. Which left me with a working query:

```
return DB::table('tickets')
                     ->leftjoin('tickets_statuses', 'tickets.ticket_id', '=', 'tickets_statuses.ticket_id')
                     ->select('tickets.organisation', DB::raw('COUNT(tickets.ticket_id) as tickets'))
                     ->where('tickets_statuses.status_id', 0)
                     ->groupby('tickets.organisation')
                     ->havingRaw('COUNT(tickets.ticket_id) > 1')
                     ->get();
```

Thanks to everyone who replied!